# jQuery json handling errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using jquery's ajax function to send json to a php script and return a json set of values for front end processing.

The php script is sending the json and I am able to echo out the json from the php script and retrieve via the success function parameter.

My question is how should I be handling errors. Is there a preferred way to send exception information (validation, etc.) back to the front end, and indicate that an error has occurred in php. Should I just be packaging up such information in a json object and checking what was received.

Thanks,

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'gear.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {'json': JSON.stringify(shopping)},
   success: function(data){
      console.info(data);
   },
   error: function(data){
      console.info(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: Why do you stringify object to json before sending? Any real reason for that?

Comment: @zerkms I think he is doing `$json = json_decode($_POST['json']);` instead of geting the post data directly from `$_POST`.

Comment: @xdazz: yep, that was also my first (and the only ;-) thought ;-) That's why I asked

Comment: If you pack up error information in the json string, you process it in success: function(data){/\* here \*/}. If you return some information to the frontend not in json format, you could process it in error: function(data){/\* here \*/}

Comment: Yes I am doing a json_decode instead of getting post data. I have a multilevel tree of information I am sending, so I assume this is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend both approaches actually. Use the `error:` block to catch any server side errors (i.e. 404, 500 errors, etc), but for business exceptions respond with a different block of JSON that you can check for. Do that in `success:`.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'gear.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {'json': JSON.stringify(shopping)},
   success: function(data){
      if (data.error_message){
          alert(data.error_message);
      } else {
          console.info(data);
      }
   },
   error: function(data){
      console.info(data); //popup an uh-oh message.
   }
});
```

Comment: the $.ajax error variables are actually `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`